# Show changes to Calendar Event in view after advanced Calendar update

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am programmatically updating a calendar event from a button click in the add-on sidebar. I want to add the conferenceData to the event and have the conference appear in the event when I do so.

I am able to update the event with the conference data fine, but I have to refresh the page to see the conference in the event. How do I get the conference to appear without refresh?

I know it's possible because the zoom add-on does exactly this.

```
function createConference(e, label, uri) {
  var event = Calendar.Events.get(e.calendar.calendarId, event.id);

  event.conferenceData = {
    conferenceId: newWaitingRoom._id,
    entryPoints: [
      {
        label: label,
        entryPointType: 'video',
        uri: uri
      }
    ],
    conferenceSolution: {
      key: { type: 'addOn' },
      name: 'Digideck Live',
    }
  }

  try {
    event = Calendar.Events.update(event, e.calendar.calendarId, event.id, { conferenceDataVersion: 1 }, { 'If-Match': event.etag });
    Logger.log('Successfully updated event: ' + event.id);
  } catch (err) {
     Logger.log('Fetch threw an exception: ' + err);
     throw Error(err);
  }

  var nav = CardService.newNavigation().updateCard(createdConferenceCard);

  return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
    .setNavigation(nav)
    .build();

}
```

Zoom Add-on example

picture 1:
[before clicking Add Meeting button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDUap.png)

picture 2:
[after clicking Add Meeting Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0Wrr.png) (no other interactions, no refresh)

any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Instead of using the advanced Calendar API, you have to return

```
return CardService.newCalendarEventActionResponseBuilder()
    .setConferenceData(ConferenceData).build();
```

EDIT: also found out that setting `"currentEventAccess": "READ_WRITE"` in the appsscript.json file is important to be able to get conferenceData from selected events via "eventOpenTrigger" etc